# Fetch user related data

Tags: user-meta

In my WordPress installation every User has an Organization. I am fetching user data using `get_user_meta ($user->ID)`. With these data I can fetch Organization ID.

Organizations are saved as Custom Post.

How can I fetch Organization name ?

Comment: how are you storing the organisation ID/name? There's no information about how organisations are stored in the question

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. Organizations are saved as Custom Post.

Comment: how are orgs connected to users though? Authors? You mentioned `get_user_meta` so I assume there's a meta key with the organization ID but you did not share the name of the key. Did you implement Organisations or is this a plugin feature? You didn't name any plugins so I'm assuming this is code that you personally wrote. Keep in mind that 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic here, but also that it's not possible to answer your question if we do not know the name of the key that holds the org ID. The only way we'd be able to find out is if it was a plugin and that would be offtopic

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. Meta Key is organization.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function on functions.php in all my development websites

```php
function imp($a){
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($a);
  echo '</pre>';
  die();
}
```

now just use imp($user); where you are using get_user_meta ($user->ID).
you will have all the info about the $user, maybe this will tell you the answer you need...

You will find inside an object with 'ID', that's why you can call $user->ID, if it were an array was possible to call $user['ID'].
normally with this function you can get all the info, sometimes are needed wordpress functions to get the info e.g. $user->get_ids(). but normally it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks @tiago calado. I am fetching these data using AJAX. My code is like below. `$names = array();
foreach ($users_found as $user) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_podsrel` WHERE `related_item_id` =  '$user->ID' AND `pod_id` = 17  AND `field_id` = 25";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    $names[$user->ID] = [ $user->display_name, count($results), get_user_meta ($user->ID) ];
}
 
echo json_encode($names);
die;`. Thanks.

Comment: this is what I was saying, foreach($users_found as $user){imp($user);}

Answer (score 1):

try this: `get_user_meta ($user->ID, 'CUSTOM-META-FIELD-NAME')`;